# Selectively expand associations in Spring Data Rest response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a standard Spring data JPA and Spring data Rest setup which, correctly, returns associations as links to the correct resources.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "version": 2,
    "date": "2011-11-22",
    "description": "XPTO",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8000/api/domain/1"
        },
        "otherDomain": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8000/api/domain/1/otherDomain"
        }
    }
}
```

However in **some** requests i would like to have the association to the "otherDomain" expanded (so the client does not have to do N+1 requests to get the full data).

Is it possible to configure Spring Data Rest to handle the response in this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [spring-data-rest, can you provide full details of entity instead of (or with) link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975618/spring-data-rest-can-you-provide-full-details-of-entity-instead-of-or-with-li)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The default responses will have to stay the same to make sure the payloads for `PUT` requests are symmetric to the ones `GET`s return. However, Spring Data REST introduces a feature called projections (see the [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-221) for details) that works as follows:

You create a dedicated interface and add all properties that you want to include in the response:

```
public interface MyProjection {

  String getMyProperty();

  MyRelatedObject getOtherDomain();
}
```

You can either

- annotate the interface using `@Projection` and place it in the very same package as the domain type or a subpackage of it
- or you manually register the projection using  the `RepositoryRestConfiguration` and call `projectionConfiguration().addProjection(…)` manually (by extending `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` and overriding `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(…)`).

This will cause the resources exposed for the domain type to accept a `projection` parameter (name also configurable `ProjectionConfiguration`) with the name of the projection. If given, we will skip the default rendering (which includes rendering links to related entities instead of embedding them) and let Jackson render a proxy backing the given interface.

An example of that can also be found in the [Spring RESTBucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks) project. See the [`OrderProjection`](https://github.com/odrotbohm/spring-restbucks/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/order/web/OrderProjection.java) for the interface definition.

Comment: Is it possible to expand further down the hierarchy via projections? For example if the object behind `otherDomain` itself has an association to `oneMoreDomain`, could this also be added to the original response?

Comment: I think if your `getOtherDomain()` method of `MyProjection` returns a projection to `oneMoreDomain` then it is possible.

Comment: @Oliver Gierke, YOU SAVED ME SOME BACON! This really should be in official docs, I wonder why it isn't :( http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/ I actually want to expand some `EAGER` associations for the default projection, but I can't seem to do that :( Do you know how? So for now, `@Projection` works... Filed https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-419

Comment: Oliver, I don't think the reference docs mention the same-package-or-subpackage requirement.

Comment: @WillieWheeler - Good catch, I created [DATAREST-508](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-508) for that.

Comment: If I need a inline object with id, how to get including id in the inlined Object?

Answer (score 1):

My solution applies to *all* requests, but some might find it relevant.

I have a simular situation, where I have the **userPersons** association nested in my **User** json response, like so:

```
{
"_embedded":{
  "users":[
     {
        "userName":"Albert"
        "userPersons":[
           {
              "personId":2356,
              "activeBoolean":1
           },
           {
              "personId":123617783,
              "activeBoolean":1
           }
        ],
        "_links":{
           "self":{
              "href":"http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
           }
        }
     }
  ]
```

}
}

My base entity like so:

```
@Entity
public class User {


...

@Getter @Setter
private String userName;

@Getter @Setter
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Userperson> userPersons;
```

}

And a single repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

My solution is this:

By simply ***NOT*** exposing a Userperson @RepositoryRestResource, Spring Data Rest will embed your association.

If you define a @RepositoryRestResource for the nested type, Spring Data Rest will render a link to the resource and not embed it.

If you need the nested type repository for internal business logic, set it to @RepositoryRestResource(exported = false), to have the same behavior.

To avoid the 1+N problem, you can configure the association for eager loading, perhaps using an @EntityGraph like [this guy](https://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/using-namedentitygraph-to-load-jpa-entities-more-selectively-in-n1-scenarios/) - though I yet haven't found the best way to implement this in Spring Data Rest.