# How to override excerpt projection

Tags: projection, spring-data-rest

I have an excerpt defined on a Repo like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = ListAccountProjection.class)
public interface IAccountRepository extends IRepository<Account> {
```

When I exec GET /accounts it works like expected.

I have another Projection ShortAccountProjection.

When I exec GET /accounts?projection=short it is simply ignored. So the projection param will never override the exerpt projection from the repo?

When I remove the excerpt from the repo, the projection "sort" works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you define an excerpt projection, it is always applied when the collection resource is accessed (`/accounts` in your case), or the resources is added as *_embedded* within another resource.

Your *ShortAccountProjection* will apply only for item resources (e.g. `GET /accounts/{id}?projection=short`).

Eventually, take a look at [Why is an excerpt projection not applied automatically for a Spring Data REST item resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220333/why-is-an-excerpt-projection-not-applied-automatically-for-a-spring-data-rest-it)

Comment: OK, this is how it works, but not why it works this way. The excerpt is a kind of preview. But when I explicitly request another projection, it should IMHO respect this. I cannot see why it should not...

Comment: I agree with you, can't see a reason why it shouldn't work as you described. Maybe an idea for future release of SDR?