# Spring Data REST: projection representation of single resource

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a simple `UserRepository` which exposed using `Spring Data REST`.
Here is the `User` entity class:

```
@Document(collection = User.COLLECTION_NAME)
@Setter
@Getter
public class User extends Entity {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "users";

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>(0);
}
```

I've created a `UserProjection` class which looks the following way:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Projection(types = User.class)
public interface UserProjection {

    String getId();

    String getName();

    String getEmail();

    Set<UserRole> getRoles();
}
```

Here is the repository class:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = User.COLLECTION_NAME, path = RestPath.Users.ROOT,
        excerptProjection = UserProjection.class)
public interface RestUserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    // Not exported operations

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Override
    <S extends User> S insert(S entity);

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Override
    <S extends User> S save(S entity);

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Override
    <S extends User> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entites);
}
```

I've also specified user projection in configuration to make sure it will be used.

```
config.getProjectionConfiguration().addProjection(UserProjection.class, User.class);
```

So, when I do **GET** on **/users** path, I get the following response (projection is applied):

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "name" : "Yuriy Yunikov",
      "id" : "5812193156aee116256a33d4",
      "roles" : [ "USER", "ADMIN" ],
      "email" : "yyunikov@gmail.com",
      "points" : 0,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/5812193156aee116256a33d4"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/5812193156aee116256a33d4{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/profile/users"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

However, when I try to make a **GET** call for single resource, e.g. **/users/5812193156aee116256a33d4**, I get the following response:

```
{
  "name" : "Yuriy Yunikov",
  "email" : "yyunikov@gmail.com",
  "password" : "123456",
  "roles" : [ "USER", "ADMIN" ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/5812193156aee116256a33d4"
    },
    "user" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/5812193156aee116256a33d4{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

As you may see, the password field is getting returned and projection is not applied. I know there is `@JsonIgnore` annotation which can be used to hide sensitive data of resource. However, my `User` object is located in different application module which does not know about API or JSON representation, so it does not make sense to mark fields with `@JsonIgnore` annotation there.

I've seen a post by @Oliver Gierke [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30297320) about why excerpt projections are not applied to single resource automatically. However, it's still very inconvenient in my case and I would like to return the same `UserProjection` when I get a single resource. Is it somehow possible to do it without creating a custom controller or marking fields with `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: You may be able to use a `ResourceProcessor` to accomplish this (or a similar effect). There's some potentially useful discussion in the comments at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-428

Comment: @CollinD Thanks for a great link! Seems like solutions with `ResourceProcessor` or `ResourceAssembler` fits good for such cases. However I'm still wondering why there is no kind of annotation or configuration in Spring Data REST for this.

Comment: ResourceProcessor is now RepresentationModelProcessor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56126713/11451863

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to create a `ResourceProcessor` class which applies projections on any resource as suggested in [DATAREST-428](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-428). It works the following way: if projection parameter is specified in URL - the specified projection will be applied, if not - projection with name default will be returned, applied first found projection will be applied. Also, I had to add custom `ProjectingResource` which ignores the links, otherwise there are two `_links` keys in the returning JSON.

```
/**
 * Projecting resource used for {@link ProjectingProcessor}. Does not include empty links in JSON, otherwise two 
 * _links keys are present in returning JSON.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
class ProjectingResource<T> extends Resource<T> {

    ProjectingResource(final T content) {
        super(content);
    }
}

/**
 * Resource processor for all resources which applies projection for single resource. By default, projections
 * are not
 * applied when working with single resource, e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/580793f642d54436e921f6ca. See
 * related issue <a href="https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-428">DATAREST-428</a>
 */
@Component
public class ProjectingProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Object>> {

    private static final String PROJECTION_PARAMETER = "projection";

    private final ProjectionFactory projectionFactory;

    private final RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration;

    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    public ProjectingProcessor(@Autowired final RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration,
                               @Autowired final ProjectionFactory projectionFactory,
                               @Autowired final HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.repositoryRestConfiguration = repositoryRestConfiguration;
        this.projectionFactory = projectionFactory;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<Object> process(final Resource<Object> resource) {
        if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(resource.getContent())) {
            return resource;
        }

        final Optional<Class<?>> projectionType = findProjectionType(resource.getContent());
        if (projectionType.isPresent()) {
            final Object projection = projectionFactory.createProjection(projectionType.get(), resource
                    .getContent());
            return new ProjectingResource<>(projection);
        }

        return resource;
    }

    private Optional<Class<?>> findProjectionType(final Object content) {
        final String projectionParameter = request.getParameter(PROJECTION_PARAMETER);
        final Map<String, Class<?>> projectionsForType = repositoryRestConfiguration.getProjectionConfiguration()
                .getProjectionsFor(content.getClass());

        if (!projectionsForType.isEmpty()) {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(projectionParameter)) {
                // projection parameter specified
                final Class<?> projectionClass = projectionsForType.get(projectionParameter);
                if (projectionClass != null) {
                    return Optional.of(projectionClass);
                }
            } else if (projectionsForType.containsKey(ProjectionName.DEFAULT)) {
                // default projection exists
                return Optional.of(projectionsForType.get(ProjectionName.DEFAULT));
            }

            // no projection parameter specified
            return Optional.of(projectionsForType.values().iterator().next());
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at something similar recently and ended up going round in circles when trying to approach it from the Spring Data /Jackson side of things.

An alternative, and very simple solution, then is to approach it from a different angle and ensure the Projection parameter in the HTTP request is always present. This can be done by using a Servlet Filter to modify the parameters of the incoming request.

This would look something like the below:

```
public class ProjectionResolverFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static final String REQUEST_PARAM_PROJECTION_KEY = "projection";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (shouldApply(request)) {
            chain.doFilter(new ResourceRequestWrapper(request), res);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return True if this filter should be applied for this request, otherwise
     *         false.
     */
    protected boolean shouldApply(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath().matches("some-path");
    }

    /**
     * HttpServletRequestWrapper implementation which allows us to wrap and
     * modify the incoming request.
     *
     */
    public class ResourceRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public ResourceRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getParameter(final String name) {
            if (name.equals(REQUEST_PARAM_PROJECTION_KEY)) {
                return "nameOfDefaultProjection";
            }

            return super.getParameter(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not quite fits what I'm looking for as what I'm interested in is the default resource representation without passing projection parameter. Also it looks more like a "hack" for me, would be much better to do it with `ResourceProcessor`, e.g. like in link provided by @CollinD. But thanks for suggestion anyway.

Comment: The solution prevents the need for passing the projection parameter as it is applying the default projection automatically- as if it had been passed in the request. Yes, it is a bit of a hack but it's simple and it works. I would be interested in seeing the custom resource processor working if you can post as an answer  if you get a solution.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it does prevents the need for passing the projection parameter. However, you still need to hardcode the path in `shouldApply` method or it can apply to all resources? I'll check later with the resource processors and would post an answer if it will work.

Comment: Yes, or you could inject the necessary SDR config  to lookup resource paths dynamically possibly.

Comment: I wrote the `ResourceProcessor` which does what expected, so you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks @Yuriy. Useful to know.