# Migrating ResourceProcessor to HATEOAS 1.0.0 M1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

In my current Spring HATEOAS 0.25.1.RELEASE project I make heavy use of 
 [ResourceProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.18.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceProcessor.html) interfaces:

```
 @Bean
 public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Person>> personProcessor() {
    return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Person>>() {
      @Override
      public Resource<Person> process(Resource<Person> resource) {
       resource.add(new Link("http://localhost:8080/people", "added-link"));
       return resource;
      }
    };
 }
```

How can can I migrate my ResourceProcessors to Spring HATEOAS 1.0.0 M1?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Spring HATEOAS 1.0 M1, a lot of types and APIs have changed naming conventions.

In your example `ResourceProcessor` is now `RepresentationModelProcessor`, and `Resource<T>` is now `EntityModel<T>`, like so:

```
public RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<Person>> personProcessor() {
return new RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<Person>>() {
  @Override
  public EntityModel<Person> process(EntityModel<Person> entityModel) {
    entityModel.add(new Link("http://localhost:8080/people", "added-link"));
    return entityModel;
  }
};
```

}

See the full change notes [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/05/spring-hateoas-1-0-m1-released)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Have you found any documentation regarding this in particular?

Comment: Seems like this is missing from the documentation however, so thank for this!