# How to acess an entity under _links in Angular from Spring Data REST?

Tags: json, angular, api, spring-data-rest

I encountered a problem which is very challenging to my Angular level. Could you give a help please?

In Spring Data REST the entity `Worker` has a `@OneToMany` bidirectional relationship with the entity `TempworkEvent`, shown below under `_links`. I would like to access `TempworkEvent` objects and their attributes through this relationship.

```
{
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Nadja Miller",
  "profession" : "Experte/in Anästhesiepflege",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3"
    },
    "worker" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3"
    },
    "tempworks" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3/tempworks"
    },
    "tempworkEvents" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3/tempworkEvents"
    }
}
```

In Angular the `Worker` entity successfully:

```
getWorkers(): Observable<Worker[]> {
   return this.httpClient.get<GetResponseWorkers>(this.workersUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response._embedded.workers)
   );
}

(...)

interface GetResponseWorkers {
  _embedded: {
    workers: Worker[];
  }
}
```

The challenge is how to access the `Worker`'s `tempworkEvents` object and its attributes through `_links`:

```
"tempworkEvents" : {
   "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3/tempworkEvents"
}
```

Comment: `worker._links.tempworkEvents` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks Will, how can I access the object attributes that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of:

1. Make an additional network request to get the `TempworkEvent`s
2. Don't have a `TempworkEvent` JPA repository, and Spring Data Rest will include the `tempworkEvents` data in the `workers` response
3. or, use a [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-data-examples.projections), like:

in `entities/projections/MyWorkerProjection.java`:

```
@Projection(name="foo", types={Worker.class})
public interface MyWorkerProjection {
  Long getId();
  String getName();
  String getProfession();
  List<TempworkEvent> getTempworkEvents();
}
```

Then call `http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3?projection=foo`

If you want to have "auto" projections, see: [Spring Data REST: projection representation of single resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289665/spring-data-rest-projection-representation-of-single-resource)

You may want to create another interface for TempworkEvent, if you want to project its data as well as its links

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Nadja Miller",
  "profession" : "Experte/in Anästhesiepflege",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3"
    },
    "worker" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3"
    },
    "tempworks" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3/tempworks"
    },
    "tempworkEvents" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/workers/3/tempworkEvents"
    }
  }
}
console.log('tempworkEvents',obj._links.tempworkEvents);
```

You can access the object like above.

Comment: Thanks rohithpoya. But that way I would be accessing the URI, I would like to access the the object itself in the same call without having to make another backend request.

Comment: If you don't want to make a second backend request, you need to change your backend response to include the properties you need.