# findAll clashes with findAll with CrudRepository in Projections

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

**Login**

```
@ApiModel
@Entity
public class Login {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private LocalDateTime loginDateTime;

    /** Other fields ***/
}
```

**LoginDateOnly**

```
interface LoginDateOnly {

    @Value("#{target.loginDateTime.toLocalDate()}")
    LocalDate getDateFromLoginDateTime();

}
```

**LoginRepository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "login", path = "login")
public interface LoginRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Login, Long> {

    Collection<LoginDateOnly> findAll();

    /** Other query methods **/
}
```

I simply want to get **all** my Login record, with **LocalDate part** of my `loginDateTime` selected/projected using a `http://host/api/login`. But currently I'm encountering a clash with CrudRepository's findAll(). How to solve this as much as possible using projection. I'm making @Query and @NamedQuery my last resort.

Comment: You have to write `@Query("Select * from Login")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `findAll` method signature is:

```
List<T> findAll();
```

If you want to override it you cannot use another signature.

All you need to get a list of your projections is define another method for this, for example:

```
Collection<LoginDateOnly> findAllBy();
```

But as I can see you are using the Spring Data REST, so in this case you don't need to define a new method. You should firstly add annotation `@Projection` to your projection:

```
@Projection(name = "loginDateOnly", types = Login.class)
interface LoginDateOnly {
    //...
}
```

Then use its name in the request url:

```
GET http://host/api/login?projection=loginDateOnly
```

See more info in the doc: [Projections and Excerpts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts)

Comment: Thanks for this, but still trying to figure out why other attributes are still returned and just the loginDate

Comment: @LemuelNabong Check the name of your projection (in `@Projection` annotation) and in the request. They must match..

Comment: exactly the same, btw I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.4.RELEASE

Comment: @LemuelNabong It doesn't matter. Try to make another projection, more simpler, for example with `getId()` only. And turn on Hibernate sql logging...

Comment: I need to place LoginDateOnly on the same package as Login or manually register the projection via RepositoryRestConfiguration.projectionConfiguration().addProjection(…) based on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220333/why-is-an-excerpt-projection-not-applied-automatically-for-a-spring-data-rest-it answer