# Spring Data REST - do not allow to return entities but only views (projections)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

My objective is to make sure that a client can't access (retrieve) directly an entity through the Spring Data REST auto-exposed APIs, but rather only to the views (JPA's projections) of those entities.

So far I've managed to achieve it only for the APIs that return a collection of entities (such as `findAll()` ) by using the `@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = CustomerView.class)` annotation on the repository.

How to configure Spring Data REST so that it does the same also for endpoints that retrieve a specific entity? such as `/api/v1/customers/1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Why is an excerpt projection not applied automatically for a Spring Data REST item resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220333/why-is-an-excerpt-projection-not-applied-automatically-for-a-spring-data-rest-it/30297320#3029732)

If you want to apply projection to a specific entity (that is, item resource),
set the uri template variable `projection` to construct a url path `/api/v1/customers/1?projection=customerView`. The name `customerView` is what is set in the annotation `@Projection`. see the doc  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections

Edit after clarify with Macro:
Macro wants to hide some sentitive fields such as password. Then the jackson annotation `@JsonIgnore` should be added to the sentitive fields to hide them from response json.

Comment: So there is no way for single resource retrieval to decouple entities? Isn't this a core security issue?
P.s: I tried to disable the endpoint `/api/v1/customers/1` but also the related projection endpoint was disabled automatically.

Comment: What do you me core security issue? Do you mean display the sensitive field such as `password` in Spring Data REST auto-exposed API? In such case, use jackson annotation `@JsonIgnore` to hide the sentitive fields.

Comment: Could you please clarify the definition of `single resource`? Is it [`item resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource) (opposite to [`collection resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource)) such as `customers/1` and `customers/2`? Or the customer with the ID 1 only?

Comment: By single resource, I mean retrieval of a single entity rather than retrieval of a List of entities. 
In my case, single resource endpoint is: `/api/v1/customers/1`
List endpoint is: `/api/v1/customers`
Hope it clarifies.

By the way, my need for a projection was indeed to hide sensitive data from the client, so `@JsonIgnore` could indeed be the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I edit my answer. Consider mark it accepted.